# Compiling Blender with Optix on Ubuntu

Tags: compile

I followed that instruction [add optix device](https://developer.blender.org/D5363) for installing Nvidia driver, Optix and compiling Blender. No errors but also no Optix in Blender. Here is debug:

> CPU flags:
>     `AVX        : True`AVX2       : True
>     AVX        : True
>     SSE4.1     : True
>     SSE3       : True
>     SSE2       : True
>     BVH layout : BVH8
>     Split      : False
>   CUDA flags:
>     Adaptive Compile : False
>   OptiX flags:
>     CUDA streams : 1
>   OpenCL flags:
>     Device type    : ALL
>     Debug          : False
>     Memory limit   : 0

My system is based on amd Ryzen 2700x, Nvidia rtx 2080, running 19.04 with Nvidia 435.17, Optix v.7
Really not sure what to think about, where to look for errors.

I don't know if my CPU is the problem and the question is which directory should I put the OptixSdk in for compiling with Blender?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about building Blender. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems/400#400

Answer (score 4):

The cmake patch for OptiX searches for the SDK in the following directories

```
SET(_optix_SEARCH_DIRS
  ${OPTIX_ROOT_DIR}
  "$ENV{PROGRAMDATA}/NVIDIA Corporation/OptiX SDK 7.0.0"
  /usr/local
  /sw # Fink
  /opt/local # DarwinPorts
)
```

Where `OPTIX_ROOT_DIR` can either be an environment variable or the path explicitly set by using `-DOPTIX_ROOT_DIR` when using cmake. `$ENV{PROGRAMDATA}` is the environment variable to the ProgramData directory, which would usually be `C:\ProgramData`.

So your OptiX SDK has to be in either one of these paths (although on Windows it should be `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\OptiX SDK 7.0.0`) and you would have to create a release build. Alternatively you can configure the cmake setup yourself and specify that you want to use Optix (unless you do a release build) using `WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPTIX=ON` and the path to the SDK `OPTIX_ROOT_DIR=/path/to/NVIDIA-OptiX-SDK-7.x.x-xxx`. This is described [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/CUDA), but can also be seen in the code of the patch. How to set these cmake variables is documented in [*Compile Blender with CMake* for building on Linux](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Template:Building_Blender/Linux/cmake) in the section for *Editing CMake Parameter* which is pretty much the same on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for detail information. Editing  the CMakeCache.txt file was a comfy solution for me. In case somebody follows the same installation instruction from that link: https://developer.blender.org/D5363 - the patch included there is not necessary for the newest blender source.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing the CMakeCache.txt file and adding the path to Optix and recompile:

```
WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPTIX=ON
OPTIX_ROOT_DIR=/path/to/NVIDIA-OptiX-SDK-7.0.0-linux64
```